# htaccess removing a specific address with a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a site where the issue has come up where I am getting a 404 error on a specific site URL with a query string. This isn't I a site I work on frequently so I am not sure if any queries should still be used. I tried this myself and it didn't work.

```
Redirect 301 /category.aspx?id=MISC34 /
```

I want the 301 direct to be specific to www.example.com/category.aspx?id=MISC34 to go to the homepage. This did not work for me. It is on Wordpress if that matters.

I am not that well versed in htaccess. Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: Query string is not a part of match in Redirect Directive, use mod_Rewrite,  Croises's answer should work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=MISC34(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^category\.aspx$ /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Certainly a cache issue. Try using a different browser

Comment: I tried it in a different browser and on a different computer and the wordpress theme that I am using doen't have a cache.

Comment: Nothing else in this htaccess file ? No error ? even if you entered garbage into the file ?

Comment: I moved it to the top of the htaccess file and it worked, so I assuming there is another error somewhere else in my file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have one that is /folder/innerfolder/?view=category and I need it to go to /new_home/ How would that look?

Comment: I tried doing the ?view=category with the sub directory and it didn't work.